# Integration over a combination of sphere and cone

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

> If $P$ is the part of the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=4$ that is above the cone $z=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, them what is $$\int_P yz \,dS?$$

I can't really visualize this problem and I'm not sure how to integration works here.

Comment: Two notes: (i) The region has a simple description in spherical coordinates. (ii) The integral can be evaluated immediately by inspection (the integrand is "odd in $y$" and the region of integration is symmetric across the $(x, z)$-plane).

Comment: How do I describe it in spherical coordinates?

Comment: The specifics depend on your definition of spherical coordinates $(\rho, \theta, \phi)$, but the region inside the sphere is described by an inequality $\rho \leq \text{constant}$, and the region above the cone has a description (similar to) $\phi \leq \text{constant}$.

Comment: But what are those constants? And are there more definitions of spherical coordinates?

Comment: To some people $\phi$ is latitude; to others, it's co-latitude; to others, it's longitude. The key point here is: If you look at the cone $z = \sqrt{x^{2} + y^{2}}$, what is the angle (in radians) between the $z$-axis and a generator? (Hint: The cone intersects the $(x, z)$-plane in the graph $z = \sqrt{x^{2}} = |x|$.) Also, what's the radius of the sphere?

Comment: The radius is 2, but how do I use that?

Comment: One set of defining conditions for your region is $0 \leq \rho \leq 2$. (Again, this _particular_ integral can be evaluated immediately by inspection, as Travis's and my comments outline. The comments here are solely for purposes of setting up integrals over this type of region.)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** The region of integration is symmetric across the $xz$-plane.

Comment: How can I use this?

Comment: Let $P_-$ and $P_+$ denote the parts of $P$ on which the $y$-coordinate is respectively negative and positive. What is the relationship between $\int_{P_-} yz \,dS$ and $\int_{P_+} yz \,dS$?

Comment: Isnt $\int_{P_-}=-\int_{P_+}$?

Comment: Yes, that's the idea. Now, what is the relationship between the integrals over $P, P_+, P_-$?

Comment: I don't know what the relation is between those

Comment: Okay, what is the relationship between $P, P_+, P_-$ themselves, rather than the integrals over them?

Comment: P is the sum of $P_-$ and $P_+$

Comment: Yes, it's the union of $P_-$ and $P_+$. Actually, as we defined it, $P_+ \cup P_-$ misses the intersection of $P$ and the $xz$-plane, but this is just a curve and so does not contribute to the value of the integral, so this omission doesn't harm us. So, this means $$\int_P yz \,dS = \int_{P_+ \cup P_-} yz \,dS.$$ Then...

Comment: I'm not sure what happens then. Can i calculate $\int_{P_+\cup P_-}yzdS$?

Comment: I think you should reread the introductory section on multivariable integration in your textbook.